# I need the Text Aligned in the middle of the page and also a thing of text at the bottom of my page in the middle

Tags: css, html

So, I would like to have my text aligned in the middle of the page and I would also like a separate div that has text on the bottom of the page in the middle.

Here is my CSS code

```
#header { text-align:center; color:white; font-family:'Capture'; font-size:34px; margin: auto; width: 800px;}
    #slogan { text-align:center }

    @font-face { font-family:'Capture'; src:url(/fonts/Capture_it.ttf); }
    .info-container { width: 840px; border: 1px solid #d8d5c6: padding: 4px; margin: 40px auto 0; }

    .inner-border { background-color: #fcfbf9; border: 1px solid #d8d5c6; padding: 10px 20px; }

    .coming-soon-visitor strong, .coming-soon-owner strong { font-weight: bold; color: #000; }

    .coming-soon-owner { float: left; font-size: 14px; color: #6d6a5b; font-weight: normal; width: 400px; border-right: 1px solid #d9d6c5; padding: 10px 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }

    .coming-soon-visitor { float: left; font-size: 14px; color: #6d6a5b; font-weight: normal; padding-left: 20px; padding: 10px 0 10px 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

Comment: Whats your problem? I don't fancy testing every bit of code for myself, please provide more information with your posts. Also this seams very simple from what you have said please try researching for yourself more. A good place to get started: http://www.tizag.com/cssT/text.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="text-align:center">Your text here</div>
```

and for your css

```
<div id="my-div">Your text here</div>

#my-div{ text-align: center }
```

if you mean, "I want my DIV centered," then you possibly want this:

```
<div id="my-div">Your text here</div>

#my-div{ width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center }
```

beyond that, your question might be too vague to give you the answer you seek

Answer (score 0):

See if the code below helps:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>align</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#text_center {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
#text_bottom {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    bottom:1%;
    margin-left:-100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text_center">Text 1</div>
    <div id="text_bottom">Text 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```